# change the initial route name for bottom sheet based on redux state

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

For react navigation 4, I have a bottom tab with 4 screens. I want to override the initial Route dynamically based on a value present in the redux -

```
const initState = {
  // route
  routeName: welcome_screen,
};
```

the routeName parameter will be passed via a function

```
const navigationHandler = (routeName) => {
  
  return routeName;
};
```

which will be passed to the `initialRouteName` for the bottom sheet

```
initialRouteName: navigationHandler(welcome_screen),
```

but when I passed it, it's giving me an error saying that the function is an instance of an object.

[complete error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCORp.jpg)
is it possible to pass a function that returns a string to the `initialRouteName`? or perhaps a better way to change the initial route name dynamically?